# Chrome URL Triple-Click Behavior

Tags: google-chrome

I know I can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>F6</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.  But is there a way to change the default behavior, as with Firefox's `about:config`, so that clicking in the URL selects it all?

I know it is only a couple of keystrokes, but....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically if there is

- no setting for this in the Chrome settings pages,
- no suitable extension in the [Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/),
- no suitable experimental flag in `about:flags` page, or
- no suitable [command-line switch](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)

there is usually nothing you can do about it.